# CSS dont work on create function on controller

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.6

I'm new in laravel. 
i following Bitfumes laravel series in youtube:

[Laravel - Create Blog and Admin Panel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMYSpg93wYU)

when i add  return view in index function like below :

```
public function index()
{
  return view('admin.post.post');
}
```

everything is perfect.
but when i move  return view to create function like :

```
public function create()
{
  return view('admin.post.post');
}
```

CSS won't work anymore . 
i dont have any idea what i must do !﻿

Comment: Make sure you load your css from an absolute path (starting with `/`).

Comment: can you please add the code where you call the CSS file or can you check firebug, if it is loading the CSS file

Comment: @devk 
this are some sample of css addresses : 
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
i include them in another main page everything is ok when the view set in index function not create or delete or etc.

Comment: @manian 
sry but the whole project is here. 
https://gitlab.com/Dr.Nefario/blog.test

Answer (score 0):

make sure your master.blade.php file is correctly link or not. If it is correctly linked after that you have to check where to you redirect the master file in controller. still you getting the same issue then use

*return return Redirect::to('post')*  //whatever you want to redirect page

hope its helpful for you.